# i want to make 5 buttons that will be hidden when clicked on it and reagain available for clicking

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a button in HTML which will be hidden after it is clicked on. A countdown should start and the button will be available for clicking after the timer finishes.

```
function startTimer() {

    document.getElementById("countdown").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
    userInput = 10;
    if (userInput.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter a value");
    } else {
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;

        function display(notifier, str) {
            document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
        }

        function toMinuteAndSecond(x) {
            return Math.floor(x / 60) + ":" + x % 60;
        }

        function setTimer(remain, actions) {
            (function countdown() {
                display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));
                actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
                (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            })();
        }

        setTimer(userInput, {
            0: function () {
                alert("Time Is Up. Please Sumbit Vote.");
                 document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "inline";
                 document.getElementById("countdown").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you errors? If yes can we see it? Or what behavior you have and what you expect?

Comment: Rephrased problem statement; removed jQuery tag (no jQuery in the code)

Comment: Your `userInput` is always `10`, and it's integer - it does not have `.length` property